# Converting a runtime Class to Constructor Code, how does the VS designer do it - Can this be improved?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, properties, constructor, designer

I'm attempting to reverse convert an object to a constructor Code-wise similar to how the Designer does it in VS2010.

Example: Font Object Properties

- Name:Microsoft Sans Serif
- Size:9.75
- Unit:Point
- Bold:False
- GdiCharSet:0
- GdiVerticalFont:False
- Italic:False
- StrikeOut:False
- Underline:False

Generates the Following in the Form Designer...

```
Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
```

---

Having a valid existing font object during runtime,

```
dim f as font = <new font code>
```

how could I get that constructor code line without specific knowledge of the class, as in automated for any class.

How does the VS designer do it anyway?

Edit:

Came up with this after reviewing the "CodeDomSerializer" from the comments, is there a better way to do this??

```
    Dim f As New Font("MS Sans Serif", 7.25!, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0, False)
    'Dim f As New Font("MS Sans Serif", 7.25!, 1 + 2 + 4, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0, False)
    'Dim f As New Point(55, 34)

    Dim dsm As New DesignerSerializationManager

    dsm.PreserveNames = True
    dsm.RecycleInstances = False
    dsm.PropertyProvider = f
    dsm.CreateSession()

    Dim cds As CodeDomSerializer = dsm.GetSerializer(dsm.PropertyProvider.GetType, GetType(CodeDomSerializer))
    Dim coce As CodeObjectCreateExpression = cds.Serialize(dsm, dsm.PropertyProvider)
    Dim tw As New StringWriter
    Dim vbcp As New VBCodeProvider

    vbcp.GenerateCodeFromExpression(coce, tw, Nothing)



    Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString)

    vbcp.Dispose()
    tw.Dispose()
    'coce
    'cds
    'dsm
    f.Dispose()
```

Generates This Line...

```
New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0,Byte))
```

Seems to work for other serialized constructors as well.

Comment: CodeDomSerializer is the base class.  Together with a bunch of derived ones that handle serialization for "difficult" Winforms classes.  This is not a general purpose code generator, it is only just good enough to get the job done for the designer.

Comment: And the Designer code is all I really was looking for, the provided class name helped much in researching this.